# Do I need to do anything special to include a .net 2 assembly in a .net 4 application?

Tags: asp.net, dll

I have an application that is a .net 4.0 app and needs to use a dll that was compiled against .net 2.0. The dll is causing the app to crash. Is there anything special I need to do to make this work?

Comment: What happens when it crashes? What's the exception?

Comment: Trying to write to protected memory.

Comment: Try putting [`useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx) in your web.config.

Comment: Do I need to add that to every code library that's using the old assembly?

Comment: @WalterFresh Possibly. It might just be easier to recompile it for .NET v4 runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the only thing that i remenber that may cause problems is the version of the dll compiled, X64 or x32

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article it's very interessant

http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2009/12/03/convert-a-net-2-0-dll-to-net-4-0-without-sourc/